# jQuery offset() returns same top value after zooming?

Tags: jquery, html

I have tried to find out bottom height of the window below the particular element. initially i take the whole window height and element height. after i have subtracted the top position of the element from window height to find bottom height. this works.
after zooming the body offset() method returns the same top position  value, so not able to find the bottom height when using zoom.
I have subtracted the top position of the element from window height to find bottom height.
 After zooming the body, offset() method returns the same top position value.

I want to calculate top position after zoom.

First sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var x = $("p").offset();
    alert("Top: " + x.top);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Return the offset coordinates of the p element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Next sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var x = $("p").offset();
    alert("Top: " + x.top);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body style="zoom:2">

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Return the offset coordinates of the p element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Zooming does not affect the computed position of an element, that's why you get the same values!

Comment: If it returns the same value after zooming then I am not able to find bottom height of the page.